# Problems implementing a Command handler in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm implementing a small component for a HR system for the office I work in. I'm currently working on allowing users to request a holiday. I'm trying my best to use Command Handlers (and hopefully Events too) as my Controllers are always very bloated.

I want to perform the following in my application:

Firstly, a User hits submit on the form to "create new request" for a holiday for example. This should go to the store() method on the RequestController and fire off a self handling command, namely CreateRequestCommand. This Command will then store the request made by the user in the DB, then carry on with functionality I haven't got round to yet.

There's two issues I'm facing while implementing the aforementioned:

Firstly, my form has a file upload. As you know if I dd() the file in my controller I'll see the files properties which I can use to upload it. However if I dd() it in the handle() function of the CreateRequestCommand it shows null. So, I'm confused as to where I should be be performing the upload logic?

Secondly, my form has 9 fields which pretty much matches what I store in the database, with exception to the user_id. So usually what I'd do, and I know this is considered back practice hence why I'm trying to use Commands, is grab all the input from a form and then throw it all in a create() function of the model to store it in the DB. Now I've extracted that logic to the Command and from viewing Taylor Otwell's example here on laracasts and in the docs for the PurchasePodcastCommand (or whatever it was) I understand I need all the relevant data to be placed in the Command's constructor, this meaning I have 9 variables in the constructor. Now forgive my ignorance, but having 9 variables in the constructor just looks wrong, so I'm asking myself and now here - am I doing this right? What follows is some of the relevant code from the classes I've mentioned in the above.

app\Http\Controllers\RequestController.php

```
public function store(Requests\CreateRequestRequest $request)
{
    $this->dispatchFrom(CreateRequestCommand::class, $request);
}
```

app\Commands\CreateRequestCommand.php

```
class CreateRequestCommand extends Command implements SelfHandling {

    /**
     * Values from request
     * @var mixed
     */
    protected $requestType, $attachment, $manager, $noOfDays, $dateFrom, $dateTo, $location, $contactNumber, $cover;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($requestType, $attachment, $manager, $noOfDays, $dateFrom, $dateTo, $location, $contactNumber, $cover)
    {
        $this->requestType   = $requestType;
        $this->attachment    = $attachment;
        $this->manager       = $manager;
        $this->noOfDays      = $noOfDays;
        $this->dateFrom      = $dateFrom;
        $this->dateTo        = $dateTo;
        $this->location      = $location;
        $this->contactNumber = $contactNumber;
        $this->cover         = $cover;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // store to db here
        dd([
            'requestType'   => $this->requestType,
            'attachment'    => $this->attachment,
            'manager'       => $this->manager,
            'noOfDays'      => $this->noOfDays,
            'dateFrom'      => $this->dateFrom,
            'dateTo'        => $this->dateTo,
            'location'      => $this->location,
            'contactNumber' => $this->contactNumber,
            'cover'         => $this->cover,
        ]);
    }

}
```

Thanks very much indeed to anyone who can offer any advice. If you need to see more code or anything I'd be happy to share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having nine variables in the Command constructor is Not wrong at all. The command object is a DTO (data transfer object) to the handler so this is not only perfectly acceptable but also the recommended manner. The command object is in charge of making sure the handler received the required $command->vars so yes they should be in the constructor.

UPDATE:
sorry forgot your other question regarding the file upload:

To handle the uploaded file in your FormRequestObject use `$request->file('inputname')` instead of `$request->input('name')`

UPDATE:
In reply to the comment regarding having a  separate command handler object,

In Laravel 5 you can either have a CommandObject that handles the command with itself or have a separate handler.

To create a self handling command object:
`php artisan make:command NameOfCommand`

This will create a command in app/Commands and it will have a constructor() and a handle() method. All the command arguments should be initiated in the constructor.

To easily create a command with a separate handler you can simply use:

`php artisan make:command NameOfCommand --handler`

This will create a  command object in app/commands with just a constructor and it will also create a command handler in app/Handlers/Commands

You should initialise your command properties in the Command object's constructor.

The command handler will have a handle() method with the CommandObject passed as an argument. This way you can use the constructor of the handler to inject other dependencies such a repositories that may be required to handle the command.

In the command handler handle() method you can get your command properties by simply typing things like `$command->attachment` etc...

This should answer all your questions :)

Update:

Change your controller method as follows:

```
// assign the request properties to variables - note the file is handled differently. 
$requestType = $request->get('requestType'); 
$attachment = $request->file('attachment'); 
$manager = $request->get('manager'); 
$noOfDays = $request->get('noOfDays'); 
$dateFrom = $request->get('dateFrom'); 
$dateTo = $request->get('dateTo'); 
$location = $request->get('location'); 
$contactNumber = $request->get('contactNumber'); 
$cover = $request->get('cover'); 

// dispatch the command 
return $this->dispatch(new CreateRequestCommand($requestType, $attachment, $manager, $noOfDays, $dateFrom, $dateTo, $location, $contactNumber, $cover));
```

Comment: Great to have clarification on the command object, thank you. Regarding the file upload though, I'm still a little confused. I'd previously thought that I needed to perform the file upload logic in the `handle()` method. Where are you suggesting I perform it? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize your handle method is on the same Command object. I prefer to have a CommandObject (dto) and a seperate command handler object but it's the same outcome so you can eitehr have a hanlde() method in your command object as you do or else create a CommanHandler object which has a handle() method. Either one can get the file using $request->file('attachment').

Comment: I explained this a bit further in my answer :)

Comment: Right - what I'm confused about is how I'm accessing the $request object in the handle method, whether it be in the Command via self handling or in a separate handler. So would I need to pass my FormRequestObject to the handle method or constructor to be able to access the $request variable? I'd originally passed this to the controller?! Apologies for all the questions!

Comment: Thanks for your extra explanation, but still a little confused regarding accessing the $request variable you mentioned in your first comment. See my previous comment. Again, many thanks Keithm you're being a huuuge help!

Comment: In your current setup you have already assigned the request parameters to the command properties(in your constructor). therefore in your handle method you simply need to do $this->dateFrom or $this->cover like you're doing. You are already passing them from the controller `$this->dispatchFrom(CreateRequestCommand::class, $request);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74641/discussion-between-keithm-and-haakym).